# Отслеживание изменения данных в таблице SQL

Tags: php, sql

Таблица в базе данных:

```
|id |имя пользователя   |дата       |значения   |
|1  |иван               |30-11-2019 |значение1  |
|2  |николай            |           |значение2  |
```

Форма заполнение данных:

```
id, имя пользователя, дата, значение
```

Данные заносятся в таблицу через команду `UPDATE`, так как мне нужно поменять имя на другое.

Вторая таблица, в нее фиксирую изменения первой таблицы, в таблицу я  добавляю данные через `INSERT`, подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так что бы вторую таблицу у меня записывалось старое имя?

```
|id |старое имя | новое имя |дата изменения |значения   |
|1  |иван       | сергей    |дата изменения |значения   |
|2  |николай    | александр |дата изменения |значения   |
```

Comment: почему бы вам не использовать триггер при обновлении таблицы?

Comment: Теоретически - да, триггер. Практически же разумнее процедуры вместо запросов (серверная логика). Не менее эффективен и вариант замены корректировки на вставку плюс флаг валидности (с соотв. партиционированием).

Comment: @teran спасибо за подсказку

Comment: @Akina сделал с помощью триггера =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение воспользоваться триггером:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER `название триггера` `trigger_time` с trigger_event ON `название таблицы`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   INSERT INTO 'название таблицы 2' Set trigger_stmt  ;
END;
```

`trigger_time` — Время срабатывания триггера. `BEFORE` — перед событием. `AFTER` — после события.

`trigger_event` — Событие:
`insert` — событие возбуждается операторами insert, data load, replace

`update` — событие возбуждается оператором update

`delete` — событие возбуждается операторами delete, replace. Операторы DROP TABLE и TRUNCATE не активируют выполнение триггера

`trigger_stmt` - выражение, которое выполняется при активации триггера

Мои запрос выглядит так

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER 'update_user' BEFORE UPDATE ON 'table1'
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   INSERT INTO 'table02 Set' 'старое имя' = old.имя пользователя, 'новое имя' = new.имя пользователя;
END;
```

После этой команды у меня стали данные записываться правильно.

Comment: хорошо)........

Comment: Вы напрасно не сохраняете дату и время изменения, наверное. Особенно если в изменениях разных записей требуется согласование... или в таблице изменений есть поле штампа с `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`? Кроме того, запись в лог ляжет даже в случае, когда обновление не выполнится по ошибке - это правильно?

Comment: @Akina у меня время записывается, это просто тестовая таблица, вот время https://prnt.sc/q4jhag

Comment: @Akina так триггер выполняется если было обновление или создание, то только тогда будет занесение в таблицу, а если обновления или создание ушло в ошибку то и триггер не выполнится. я не тестировал пока на ошибки,  если будут то я дальше буду читать мануал и изучать триггеры и процедуры

Comment: @Akina если триггер выполняется при любом случае, то в первую таблицу писать статус выполнения скрипта c помощью elseif, а таблица 2 уже будет брать триггером статус выполнения записи первой таблицы и тогда я увижу было ли добавление или нет, то есть добавление в таблицу будет в любом случае

Comment: *триггер выполняется если было обновление или создание, то только тогда будет занесение в таблицу, а если обновления или создание ушло в ошибку то и триггер не выполнится.* BEFORE начхать на ошибки исполнения запроса (но не на ошибки, скажем, типов значения). Почитайте документацию повнимательнее...

Answer (score 1):

Сначала создаём таблицу tabl2 где ты будешь логи вести

```
$conn = new mysqli('1', 'r', 'p', 't');
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

 mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");  //обязательный параметр

$sql = "CREATE TABLE tabl2 (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
oldname* VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
newname* VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
reg_date TIMESTAMP,
znachenie* VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
)";
```

Потом страничку для обновления

```
<?php

echo '<form action= "post.php" method= "POST">'; 

echo '<p>Новое Имя: </p><p> <input type= "text" name= "name"> </p>'; 

echo'<p>Старое Имя: </p><p> <input type= "text" name= "oldname"></p>'; 

echo '<input type= "submit" value= "Отправить">';


if(isset($_POST['oldname'])){
  $name=$_POST['name'];
  $oldname=$_POST['oldname'];

$conn1 = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* проверка соединения */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", $conn1->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$query = "select * from tabl1 where name='".$oldname."'";
$result = $conn1->query($query);
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$arr2[]=$row2;
}

$znach=$arr2[0]['znachenie'];

$sql = "UPDATE tabl1 SET name='".$name."' WHERE name='".$oldname."'";

if ($conn1->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn1->error;
}

$query1 = "INSERT INTO tabl2 (oldname, newname, znachenie) VALUES ( '". $oldname."','".$name."','".$znach."')";

if (mysqli_query($conn1, $query1)) {

echo "<br>"."Dobavleno";
  }else{
    echo "Oshibka".mysqli_error($conn1);
  }


}
?>
```

Comment: код у меня уже есть, передаю я в запись через два ajax один на обновление в одну в таблиц, а другой на запись в другую таблицу, у меня был вопрос как передать запись страницы до ее изменения

Comment: сделай так) тут вся последовательность делает то что тебе нужно, можешь свой ajax оставить

Comment: к сожалению этот метод не подходит ко мне, мне необходимо это сделать через процедуры как написали выше, я почитаю лучше мануалы, а позже сам сделаю ответ и это поможет другим)

Comment: ответ сделал выше только не через процедуры, а через тригеры