# хочу сохранить данные из input в базе данных пользователя, но почему-то не получается

Tags: php, mysql

```
<form action="" method="post">
<h4>Введите количество собранной картошки</h4>
<div class="block">
<label>2019<input name="pro19" id="pro19" type="text" class="form-control"> 
</label>
</div>
<button type="submit" id="save" name="save" class="btn btn-success  mt- 
5">Сохранить</button>
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "bp");

if (!$link) {
echo "Ошибка: Невозможно установить соединение с MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
echo "Текст ошибки error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
exit;
}

if(empty($_POST['pro19'])) {
                $_POST['pro19'] = 0;
            }


$save=$_POST['save'];


if(isset($save)) {

if(isset($pro19)) {

$query = "INSERT INTO `resa`(`kartoshka`) VALUES ('{$pro19}')";
if(mysqli_query($db_connect, $query))
{
echo "Запись добавлена!";
}
}
}
else {
echo "что-то пошло не так";
}


?>
```

Comment: примерно так вставка делается $query1 = "INSERT INTO tabl2 (oldname, newname, znachenie) VALUES ( '". $oldname."','".$name."','".$znach."')";

Comment: ну и устаревшую конструкцию заменить https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1052569/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b5-sql/1052656#1052656

Comment: конкретнее можно?

Comment: как это будет выглядеть у меня?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['pro19'])){
$pro19=$_POST['pro19'];
$conn1 = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "bp");

/* проверка соединения */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Не удалось подключиться: %s\n", $conn1->connect_error);
    exit();
}
$query1 = "INSERT INTO resa (kartoshka) VALUES ('".$pro19."')";

if (mysqli_query($conn1, $query1)) {

echo "<br>"."Dobavleno";
  }else{
    echo "Oshibka".mysqli_error($conn1);
  }
}
```

Comment: для начала так, но это небезопасная конструкция